# Saving Numpy array using scipy.io.savemat MATLAB does not produce the necessary .mat file

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, scipy

I have written a function to convert a NumPy array into a mat file using  scipy.io.savemat() but it produces a generic type of file: File with the same name but not of type .mat as expected. The array I want to save is of type <class 'numpy.ndarray'> as verified by the print statement. I don't know what may be the issue.

```py
 
import os
import scipy.io

def save_electrode_measurement_to_matfile( measurement: np.ndarray, file_name: str = 'latest_electrode_measurement'):
    print(type(measurement))
    mdict = { 'electrode_measurement' : measurement}
    dir = r"...\Simulation_results"
    file_path = os.path.join(dir, file_name)
    scipy.io.savemat(file_path, mdict, appendmat = True)
```

Comment: Have you tried having the filename include the extension .mat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refering to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html), I think that you should add '.mat' to the filename (which is the file_path in your case).
By replacing

```
file_path = os.path.join(dir, file_name)
```

> with

```
file_path = os.path.join(dir, file_name) + ".mat"
```

Your problem should be solved.

Comment: It worked, thank you! Apologies, I was under the impression that was what appendmat optional argument did.

Comment: `appendmat` works as you expected - at least in my tests.  Actually adding the `mat` is the default behavior.  Does you filename already have something that looks like an extension?

Comment: I don't fully follow the code that appends the '.mat' if not 'already present' (it's buried several function calls down), but it looks like it's easily fooled.  So it's probably safer to include your own.